# How does $-\frac{([1+\cos(x)][1-\cos(x)]}{\cos^2(x)\:}$ become $\:-\frac{1+\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm working through Tom Apostol's volume 1 of *Calculus*, and on page 293 he gives the following equation when trying to calculate L'Hospital's rule.

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\tan(x)}{x-\sin(x)}$

I understand how he gets to this reduced calculation here:

$-\frac{([1+\cos(x)][1-\cos(x)]}{\cos^2(x)}$

I know that the top can be reduced to:

$$-\frac{([1+\cos(x)][1-\cos(x)]}{\cos^2(x)} = -\frac{([1+\cos(x)][1-\cos(x)]}{1-\sin^2(x)}=-\frac{([1+\cos(x)][1-\cos(x)]}{[1+\sin(x)][1-\sin(x)]}$$

Though, I'm unsure of how he gets the final quotient as:

$-\frac{1+\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$

You're help will be greatly appreciated!

As per @Babado's request:

(7.24) $$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\frac{1-\sec^2(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}$$

"Although this, too, assumes the form 0/0 as $x \to 0$, we may remove the indeterminacy at this stage by algebraic means. If we write"

$$1-\sec^2(x)=1-\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} = \frac{\cos^2(x)-1}{\cos^2(x)}=-\frac{(1+\cos(x))(1-\cos(x))}{\cos^2(x)}$$

The quotient in (7.24) becomes

$$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=-\frac{1+\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$

Comment: Please clarify your question. We don't know the sequence of steps it is taken in the book (without opening it) and if the last equality is indeed an equality or if it has a limit involved.

Comment: The line of equations you give here is not (7.24), he is only simplifying the numerator of (7.24).  When he divides by the $1-\cos x$ in the denominator, you get the quotient he gives as the simplified version of (7.24).

Comment: @Babado It's been added!

Comment: @MatthewDaly That's my uncertainty. How exactly is he able to divide the denominator by $1-\cos(x)$, I can imagine it only looking like: $\frac{(1+cos(x))}{cos(x)}\cdot \frac{((1-cos(x)))}{cos(x)}$

Comment: Unless we can do something like: $\frac{1+cos(x)}{cos(x)}\cdot \frac{1-cos(x)}{cos(x)(1-cos(x))}$, perhaps there's a simply algebraic/arithmetic proof towards this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\tan x}{x-\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x-\tan x)'}{(x-\sin x)'}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\frac1{\cos^2x}}{1-\cos x}\\
=-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\frac{1-\cos^2x}{1-\cos x}
=-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+\cos x}{\cos^2x}
$$

Comment: AHA! I can see what @Mathewdaly meant, I completely missed to recognise that the numerator was a **separate** equation, hence there still was $\frac{1}{x-sin(x)}$ hence $\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)}$ to include into the equation. Thanks for the response!